# Счётный оборот со словом "сколько" и отрицанием "ни"

Tags: синтаксис

*Вот диалог:*

> — Сколько сёл затопило в Крыму?
>
> — ***Ни сколько сёл не затопило в Крыму***.

Вот такой вот ответ на вопрос.

Можно, ясное дело, пойти по лёгкому пути и ответить что-то вроде "Ни одного села не затопило в Крыму" или "В Крыму ничего не затопило". Понятно.  А вот такой ответ как вам?

Есть ли основания для его синтаксической (именно для синтаксической, а не вкусовой или стилистической) неправильности?

Как известно, при переходных с отрицанием "не" используется в общем родительный, ежели есть усиливающая отрицание "ни".

Что я съел? — Я не съел ничего. Родительный убедительный.

Сколько сёл затопило в Крыму? — Ни скольких сёл не затопило в Крыму. Родительный странно звучащий.

Тогда винительный остаётся использовать при отрицании.

Вообще — это главный вопрос! — можно ли на вопрос "Сколько сёл затопило в Крыму?" ответить репликой с тем же лексическим составом, но с отрицанием. То есть счётный оборот именно в этом лексическом составе (сколько сёл) можно сохранить в ответной реплике?

Он дал тебе пять конфет? — Он не дал мне пять конфет.  Вот тот же лексический состав, тот же винительный счётного оборота, но с "не" перед глаголом в ответе.

Сколько сёл затопило в Крыму? — Ни сколько сёл не затопило в Крыму. Вот тот же лексический состав, тот же винительный счётного оборота, но с "не" перед глаголом, а кроме того, с "ни" перед счётным.

Comment: Люди часто так и говорят: *Сколько? Нисколько (вместе).*

Comment: Это не то. "Сколько раз отжался? - Нисколько!" Тут ясно.  Однако я говорю о сохранении счётного оборота в ответной реплике. Нельзя уже сказать "Сколько раз отжался? - Нисколько раз не отжался!" Нисколько - наречие степени, оно вряд ли может быть местоимённым числительным в счётном оборот. Речь идёт именно о возможности сохранения в ответной реплике местоимённого числительного "сколько", управляющего родительным падежом.

Comment: По справочникам, отдельно можно лишь при повторении частицы "ни": *Я не знаю ни сколько сейчас времени, ни какой сегодня день.* Крайне редко встречается вариант раздельного написания слов «ни сколько». Опознать такой случай можно так: если убрать частицу «ни» и после этого предложение не потеряет свой смысл, то следует писать «ни сколько».

Comment: А тут вы тоже отдельно напишите? *Никак не затапливало сёла в Крыму. Нигде не затопило сёла в Крыму.*

Comment: Нет, конечно.  "Как  затапливало - никак не затапливало" (отрицание и действия и образа действия, соответственно); "где затопило - нигде не затопило" (отрицается действие и место действия). Но если отрицается количество (сколько - местоимённое числительное), то как можно превращать частицу "ни" в приставку? Ни сколько сёл не затопило - частица "ни" и счётный оборот с отрицаемым числительным. "Нисколько" - в лексикографии является мест. наречием. меры и степени со значением отрицания степени, меры, количественных свойств действия или признака. "Нисколько сёл не затопило" - это разве правильно?

Comment: Правильно. Эти случаи аналогичны. Раздельно можно только так: *Он не знает ни сколько сёл затопило, ни почему это произошло.*

Comment: Количество не отрицается! Оно называется. *Сколько сёл затопило, какое количество? Нисколько [нет] сёл.*

Comment: "Нисколько сёл"  - нет таких счётных оборотов. "Ни" не может слитно писаться с числительным. А "сколько" - это числительное. А "нисколько" - это наречие меры и степени. Где такие счётные обороты, в которых наречие степени управляет существительным?

Comment: "*Сколько*" - это не числительное, а слово для образования вопроса. "*Сколько сёл*" - никак не может быть утвердительным предложением при существительном. "*Нисколько*" - это уже как числительное, вернее, слово, обозначающее отсутствие числа или ноль. "*Столько*" - местоимение как числительное, отвечающее на вопрос "*сколько?*".

Comment: Ладно, кроме "так не положено", как я вижу, ничего вы сказать не можете. ОК.

Comment: "Ни" не используется для самостоятельного отрицания. Используется при однородных элементах или при глаголе в придаточном. Не "так не положено", а это ошибка.

Comment: Ни шагу назад! Ни звука!

Comment: Ладно. Но у нас не восклицательное предложение.

Comment: По сколько рублей пришлось на каждого? Ни по сколько рублей не пришлось на каждого.

Comment: На сколько лет ты его старше.? Ни на сколько лет я его не старше.

Comment: Ну, тут предлог мешает)

Comment: "На сколько" - это пример из словаря. То есть "сколько" - это мест. числительное в вин. падеже с предлогом на. Это счётный оборот с управляемым род. падежом. Это по Ожегову, Ушакову, БАС и МАС. "Нисколько", по всей лексикографии, это наречие, неизменяемая форма. В каких примерах наречие управляет род. падежом и образует счётный оборот? "Нисколько рублей не пришлось на каждого" - во всём интернете нет такого сочетания, как и других сочетаний, где бы "нисколько" имел в зависимой позиции род. падеж имени.

Comment: "Нисколько" - это местоимение (числительного) (по словарю), похожее на наречие. Ну найдите примеры с раздельным написанием.

Comment: Нисколько - это местоимённое наречие. Ни в одном словаре русского языка оно не зовётся числительным.  Только что проверил все. Кроме того, числительные склоняются, а нисколько - это неизменяемая форма, что ещё раз подтверждает, что оно наречие. Что касается примеров, то не на всё есть примеры.

Comment: Я, честно, слов не нахожу, чтобы заявить о том, что диалог — "На сколько сантиметров ты выше его? - Ни на сколько сантиметров я его не выше?" — противоречит чьим-то синтаксическим правилам и рекомендациям?

Comment: Это разговорный вариант, слегка грубый. Нормально - это просто "*я не выше его*". В ответах весь вопрос не повторяют.

Comment: Вот, всё-таки имеет право на жизнь, не так ли? А вот это явление - "в ответах весь вопрос не повторяют" - это уже не сфера интересов синтаксиса, а сфера интереса стилистики.

Comment: У меня нет претензий к таким формулировкам: они используются довольно часто. Чем-то новым они не являются. Но претензии к раздельному написанию. В справочниках таких исключений нет.